# How to free this strdup?

Tags: c, memory, valgrind, free, strdup

I am using strdup to duplicated the value inside command. I also free it at the end of my loop to make sure I don't have anything leaking but valgrind seems to disagree with me and says that what is allocated with this strdup is leaking. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
init_ui();
hist_init(100);

char *command;
while (true) {
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
    command = read_command();
    if (command == NULL) {
        break;
    }
    char *copy = strdup(command);
    char *args[4096];
    int tokens = 0;
    char *next_tok = command;
    char *curr_tok;
    while((curr_tok = next_token(&next_tok, " \t\n\r")) != NULL) {
        if(strncmp(curr_tok, "#", 1) == 0){
            break;
        }
        args[tokens++] = curr_tok;
    }
    args[tokens] = NULL;

    if(args[0] == NULL) {
        continue;
    }
     
    hist_add(copy);
    int builtin_status = handle_builtins(tokens, args);
    if(builtin_status == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    pid_t child = fork();
    if(child == -1){
        perror("fork");
    }
    else if(child == 0){
        int ret = execvp(args[0], args);
        if(ret == -1) {
            perror("execvp");
        }
        close(fileno(stdin));
        close(fileno(stdout));
        close(fileno(stderr));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        int status;
        waitpid(child, &status, 0);
        set_last_status(status);
    }
hist_destroy();
free(copy);
}
return 0;
}
```

Here is what valgrind gives me, I really am trying to understand what is wrong because it seems like what is defined with this strdup is freed:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==359074== in use at exit: 18 bytes in 2 blocks
==359074== total heap usage: 72 allocs, 70 frees, 20,000 bytes allocated
==359074==
==359074== 18 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==359074== at 0x483977F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==359074== by 0x4A7D23E: strdup (in /usr/lib/libc-2.31.so)
==359074== by 0x10A703: main (shell.c:85)
==359074==
==359074== LEAK SUMMARY:
==359074== definitely lost: 18 bytes in 2 blocks
==359074== indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==359074== possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==359074== still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==359074== suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Comment: There's a bunch of `continue;`s before you `free(copy);` - those would obviously leak the memory

Comment: So every time I continue, I free before right?

Comment: Where do you `free()` the memory that was allocated with `command = read_command();` which was then duplicated to `*copy`?

Comment: I... don't :/ But it was not causing any problem before

Comment: Perhaps it pointed to a `static` array in `read_command();` which cannot be `free()`d. The problems of posting incomplete code...

Comment: If you want to do it right, *every* allocation must eventually be paired with a release. This is best done by implicitly tracking ownership, as in you must keep track of your responsibility at any given point in the code: You either release memory, or you pass ownership on to another part of your code.

Comment: Okay! I freed after every continue and it now works. I totally got where the code was wrong... just silly me. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strdup()` uses `malloc()` to allocate memory, so in order to reuse `strdup()`, `copy` must be freed.

As UnholySheep commented above, `continue`s causing to ignore the `free()` statement. One solution to fix this issue is to put an extra `free()` statement before each `continue`.